# Default credential for app engine project accessing google cloud storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have an app engine project, I want to access my google cloud storage default bucket. The first step of getting a Credential object fails, doing the following on a live instance:

```
Credential creds = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
```

The exception message I get:

"The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information."

The doc here says that production app engine projects should have access to the default credentials?:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

"3. If you are running in Google App Engine production, the built-in service account associated with the application will be used."

Is there some setup I'm missing?

My app engine version (gradle):

```
com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18
```

and google cloud storage lib version:

```
com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev35-1.20.0
```

Thanks

Comment: I know it's been long since this question was asked, but you can try to export this parameter with path to JSON file containing your private key data to set default google cloud account, `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/googleCredentials.json`

Answer (score 7):

Go to Google Developers Console -> Credentials and create a default service account .json key. When you do that, it will download a file like `default-account-credentials.json` for you. You must then put that file somewhere in your app engine project. This file will be referenced when you call

`Credential creds = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();`

However, before that works you must set the environmental variable to that files location. To do that open up your `appengine-web.xml` file and put this line into it:

```
<env-variables>
            <env-var name="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
                value="WEB-INF/default-account-credentials.json" />
        </env-variables>
```

Where `value` is the path to your `.json` creds file you just downloaded.

Now it will work. (your gradle imports are fine)

Comment: I have followed above steps and added the environment variables of the downloaded file. 
Still I am getting exception:
Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:484)

Please suggest if any other step needs to be done. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How to put a file in app engine? docs say app engine will automatically use default service account.

Comment: I don't this it is correct to store creds with you app, according to the documentation they must be accessible from the app engine (as the author suggests)

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this solution to help others like me who still need help with this error.
Install gcloud on your system, select the project you want to use in the gcloud window, and then authenticate yourself using this command in the gcloud window:
*"gcloud auth application-default login"* to generate a file called application_default_credentials.json. Your program running on the same system will then use this file automatically for authentication.
Follow this link to install gcloud:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc?hl=en_GB