# Google Cloud Storage - com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFailureException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to store a file to Google Cloud Storage using a jaxrs Service running in Google App Engine. While trying to store the file I am getting below error.

**com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.NonRetriableException: com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFailureException: The AppIdentity service threw an unexpected error. Details:**

I am trying to save the file to a new bucket and gave below ids (compute, app engine and service account) permissions to the bucket. I also created a separate service account and gave this service account also the Writer Permission (with Editor Role to this account to the project)

- myaccount@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
- xxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
- xxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com

I understand the service account is not required because from app engine with the default service we should be able to store the file. But just to try I also created the above service account and stored the file in WEB-INF/resources/service_account_credentials.json location and set the below property in appengine-web.xml

```
<property name="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" value="WEB-INF/resources/service_account_credentials.json"/>
```

I tried below two ways to store the file, but both are giving the error.

**First Way...**

Getting the Service

```
    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
          .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
          .retryMaxAttempts(10)
          .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000)
          .build());
```

Storing the file

```
  GcsFileOptions  gcsFileOptions = null ;
  GcsFileOptions.Builder builder = new GcsFileOptions.Builder() ;
  if(aclEntityName != null)
      builder = builder.acl(aclEntityName) ;


  if(fileMetaData != null && !fileMetaData.isEmpty())
  for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fileMetaData.entrySet()){
      builder = builder.addUserMetadata(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) ;
  }
  gcsFileOptions = builder.build() ;
  GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename(bucketName, name) ;
  GcsService gcsService = StorageFactory.getGcsService() ;
  GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, gcsFileOptions);
  copy(contentStream, Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
```

**Second Way as given below also gives the same error...**

Getting the Service

```
HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
GoogleCredential credential = 
GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory);
if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      Collection<String> scopes = StorageScopes.all();
      credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
    }
    return new Storage.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("GCS Samples")
            .build();
```

Storing the file second way

```
StorageObject objectMetaData = new StorageObject();
objectMetaData.setName(name);

if(fileMetaData != null && fileMetaData.isEmpty() == false )
    objectMetaData.setMetadata(fileMetaData) ;

    // Set the access control list to publicly read-only

if(aclEntityName != null && !aclEntityName.trim().equals("")
    && aclRole != null && !aclRole.trim().equals("") ) {
    objectMetaData.setAcl(Arrays.asList(
        new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity(aclEntityName).setRole(aclRole)));
}

InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream", contentStream);


// Do the insert
Storage client = StorageFactory.getService();
Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = client.objects().insert(
        bucketName, objectMetaData, mediaContent);    
if (mediaContent.getLength() > 0 && mediaContent.getLength() <= 2 * 1000 * 1000 /* 2MB */) {
    insertRequest.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
    }
insertRequest.execute();
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any setting I need to do to fix this error? Please help !!!

Comment: Does the exception provide any more details (after "Details:")? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: No, there is no information in-front of the Details. Just a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials), using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable should be pointing to a local file, and is generally used with `gcloud` command line tool to authenticate when testing code locally.

That said, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408645/374638, perhaps this should be in `<env-variables>` instead.