# The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

First of all, this question's scope is .NET C# so this is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982121/default-credential-for-app-engine-project-accessing-google-cloud-storage) SO Question.

I have a test code for speech recognition which I get from google documents. Code as follows:

```
public static string DEMO_FILE = "test.mp3";
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var speech = SpeechClient.Create(); //  Exception thrown here
}
```

When application runs `SpeechClient.Create();` line, exception `System.InvalidOperationException` is thrown.

**Exception message is**: *'The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.'*

**What I have done so far?**

I set up `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable with value (private key json file). I just run following command in cmd:

`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\my-file-name.json`

Also, when I print the enviroment variable in cmd by using `echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%` file path and file name is shown.

**Note:** I set environment by manuelly but it did not work.

What should I do to solve this annoying problem?

Thank you for your suggestions and tips.

**Edit**

Following line is able to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. However when app is terminated / finished, variable cannot be reached.

```
System
.Environment
.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"C:\my-path\my-private-key.json");
```

Comment: What happens when you execute this command: `type %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%`? Do you see the contents of the service account JSON key file?

Comment: Yes. file path and file name is shown

Comment: You should see the contents, not the path.

Comment: How are you then *running* the code? If you're running it from anywhere other than from that console, the environment variable won't be defined. I'd suggest adding `Console.WriteLine($"Credentials path: {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")}");` to your `Main` method so you can see if it's actually defined.

Comment: @JonSkeet I checked environment with `Console.WriteLine` and yes you're right. Environment could not be set in the cmd command. I updated question by the way.

Comment: "However when app is terminated / finished, variable cannot be reached." - yes, because that sets it for the *current process*. If you want to set it persistently, use the Windows applet - press the Windows key and type "environment" to display "Edit the system environment variables" and "Edit environment variables for your account".

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet , would you mind putting all your suggestions together as an Answer for the sake of the community? I think we came to a resolution here. Thank you.

Comment: @SergiMuñoz: Hmm... it's really a sort of "you hadn't set the environment variable properly" which doesn't feel like much of an answer, but I suppose it's better than nothing.

Comment: @FatihTAN Were you able to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you hadn't set the environment variable in a way that let your program use it. Note that:

- If you set the environment variable via the Windows applet (which is generally the best approach in my view), any *existing* command line windows won't "see" the change
- If you set the environment variable in one command line window, that doesn't affect any other window, and isn't persistent
- If you set the environment variable programatically using `SetEnvironmentVariable`, that will only affect the current process (and any processes it spawns)

If you're not sure whether the environment variable is set, it's easy to log it, e.g.

```cs
var credentialsPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
Console.WriteLine($"Credentials path: {credentialsPath}");
```

Once that's working, I'd expect the client library to be fine too.